# Unable to read values from Standard Address Dropdown list in Before Insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, class, field-update, before-trigger

am trying to read values from few fields (standard shipping address text and dropdown fields in Account object)in a before insert Account trigger.
but to my surprise, when am trying to read values from drop down fields am getting null values while inserting a record. but inserted record shows valid values in drop down lists.

while updating a record it works as expected

below is my code,

```
trigger [assignLocation] on Account (before Insert, before Update) {
 for (Account account : Trigger.new) {
        street.add(account.ShippingStreet);
        city.add(account.ShippingCity);
        state.add(account.ShippingState);
        zipCode.add(account.ShippingPostalCode);
        country.add(account.ShippingCountry);
     } 
}

     System.debug('--streetstreet --: ' + street ); // am getting desired value
     System.debug('--citycity --: ' + city ); // am getting desired  value
     System.debug('--statestate --: ' + state ); // this is drop down field, in trigger. It shows null while debugging when inserting a record.
      System.debug('--zipCode --: ' + zipCode ); // am getting desired  value
     System.debug('--countrycountry --: ' + country ); // this is drop down field, in trigger it shows null while inserting a record.
```

as i have to update a field before inserting/updating a account record .I have to use BEFORE INSERT BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER,

Thank you

Comment: There appears to be code missing from your trigger. Where are `street`, `city`, `state`, `zipCode` and `country` list variables defined at in your trigger and why are you adding the values from trigger.new to them? I assume they must be lists since your adding values to them from trigger.new.

Answer (score 1):

Since State is a picklist, I am guessing that you have State and Country picklists enabled. If that is the case, then you should use ShippingStateCode and ShippingCountryCode in your trigger.